# rub program to read numbers accepting from the user

Tags: ruby

I just started learning ruby and I was trying out a simple program to accept two numbers from the user and multiplying.

Here is my code:

```
def mult(i1,i2)
        res = i1.to_i * i2.to_i
        puts res
end

puts "enter 1st no to multiply"

i1 = gets

puts "enter 2nd no to multiply"

i2 = gets

mult(i1,i2)
```

Here I am reading two numbers through **gets** which is accepting as strings and later I am converting into integer as shown in the code.

But is there any way to accept directly as numbers datatype?

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
i1 = gets.to_i
i2 = gets.to_i
```

Comment: thanks xdazz. But are there any built in function similar to **gets**

Comment: @kattashri no, I am afraid there is not. you may creat one yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the scan method to return something only when the string has a number in it. This is one way to do it:

```
gets.scan(/[0-9]/).join.to_i
```

If no numbers get entered, the code will return 0. Otherwise, it will return the number.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [scanf](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/scanf/rdoc/Scanf.html) module. It is similar to the c functionality. I think it should be more efficient then what you do.

Comment: i tried but its throwing error... "can't convert Array into Integer (TypeError)"

Comment: scanf returns an array. Maybe the version with a block will help you?

Answer (score 0):

If you know C you might like scanf. It is not in the core language. Try this in IRB:

```
?> require 'scanf'
=> true

?> numberX = scanf("%d")
?> 345
=> [345]
#scanf return an array    


?> numberX
=> [345]

?> numberX.at(0)
=> 345
```